# whats the difference between LCD pixel width, height and resolution while creating AVD?(android)

Tags: android, pixel, android-virtual-device, screen-resolution

whats the difference between LCD pixel width, height and resolution  while creating an AVD for android?[image]

to be more clear, i need to develop an app for the device with resolution 1024x768 so can
anybody can help me to understand please ?

Comment: name it self says it's difference.

Comment: no i need avd of size 1024x768 pixel for my project, which one i should set to those values ? to be more clear, i need to develop an app for the device with resolution 1024x768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the resolution of the emulator in the Skin Resolution area.  The LCD Pixel Height and LCD Pixel Width settings are ignored, based on my experience.  Possibly the only time they would be used is if the skin did not specify the resolution.